# How to split a string by pattern into tokens using sed or awk

Tags: bash, sed

My input is

```
filename.b.c
```

The output I want is

```
filename
b
c
```

Can I split by the '.' character using sed or awk?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the question was about sed and awk, here's the sed version:

```
echo filename.b.c | sed 's/\./\n/g'
```

And the awk version:

```
echo filename.b.c | awk -F'.' '{for (i=1; i<= NF; i++) print $i}'
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `tr`:

```
echo filename.b.c | tr . '\n'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using BASH string manipulations:

```
s='filename.b.c'
eol=$'\n'

echo "${s//./$eol}"
filename
b
c
```

Or using `read` with `IFS`:

```
IFS=. read -ra var <<< "$s"
printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}"
filename
b
c
```

Comment: using IFS, don't forget to put it back to original just aftert manipulation or make the manipulation in a subshell (if code could use it) or you could have unexpected behaviour on following command

Comment: No need to revert `IFS` in this case as `IFS=. read -ra var <<< "$s"` sets `IFS` only for use in `read`. In shell `IFS` remains unchanged. You can check it by using `read -ra arr1 <<< "$s"` immediately after this and see the value of `arr1` array.

Answer (score 2):

You can replace `.` with a space, and then use `()` to set it as array:

```
filename=file.a.b.c
arr=(${filename//./ })
```

then you can display your array:

```
for k in "${arr[@]}";do echo "[$k]";done
```